# Stop Safari omnibar suggesting website root

Tags: macos, safari

How can I make Safari's omnibar take me to https://www.evernote.com/client/web (for example) instead of https://www.evernote.com/ when I type `evern` into the omnibar and press enter.

At the moment, even though I purposefully deleted it from my history, it takes me to evernote.com (the homepage of that website) instead of to my most frequently-accessed page and the page I would like the suggestion to land me on.

Comment: I have the specific Evernote webpage load automatically when I start my browser up, and I have the same link as a bookmark in the Bookmark bar for easy access if the window is closed. I use another browser, but the concept and execution in Safari is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Create a bookmark for the specific page you want. Bookmarks are included in omnibar results.